# Delete Repository via Nexus 3 REST API

Tags: rest, sonatype, nexus3

In the Nexus 3 Reference about its REST API and [scripting](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html) it is described how to upload Groovy scripts to Nexus 3 and how to run them. Examples are shown how to create new repositories, such as a Maven repository:

```
repository.createMavenHosted('private')
```

However, as simple as it sounds, I did not find any similar method to delete or remove an existing repository. Is that really not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried (even though I thought it would not work):

```
{
    "name" : "cleanup",
    "type" : "groovy",
    "content" : "repository.getRepositoryManager().delete('maven-public');"
}
```

Source: https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/ansible-nexus3-oss/blob/master/files/groovy/delete_repo.groovy

As it turns out, this piece of code really does work to delete the maven-public repository, if it is available ...